# How to apply promises in a node.js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to write a program that can unzip a zip file, read the images in the file and apply grayscale to them.

right now i have these two functions :

```
    var fs = require('fs'),
        PNG = require('pngjs').PNG
    const unzipper = require('unzipper')
    PNG = require('pngjs').PNG
    const dir = __dirname + "/";

    const myFile = (fileName) => {
        let createdFile = dir + fileName
        fs.createReadStream(createdFile)
            .pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: 'myfile' }));
        console.log('file unzipped')
    }


    myFile("myfile.zip")

    function applyFilter(Name) {
        fs.readdir(Name, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                data.forEach(function (file) {
                    if (file.includes('png')) {
                        let greyPNG = (__dirname + '/' + 'myfile' + '/' + file)
                        console.log (greyPNG)
                        fs.createReadStream(greyPNG)
                            .pipe(new PNG({
                                colorType: 0,

                            }))
                            .on('parsed', function () {   

                                this.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/" + "myfile" + "/" + file));
                            });
                    }
                })  
            }
        })
    }



    applyFilter ('myfile')
```

these two function works fine individually, however, it will not run together, if I comment out "applyFilter". A zip file will be unzipped. if there is a file in the directory, "applyFilter" will apply grayscale on those pictures. I know that this is because both functions runs at the same time which causes the problem. So how do I implement promises to solve this issue. I know that I can use "Sync" version of the functions. I just want to know how to do it in promises.

Comment: Is there a callback function of the unzipper? You can always refact a async functions with callback to promise simply calling the `resolve` in callback.

Answer (score 0):

There are Example's in official documentation about ‘promisify’:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

which will gives you a "promised" version of the same function (as long as the original function has a standard signature / a custom promisified definition).

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat);

async function callStat() {
  const stats = await stat('.');
  console.log(`This directory is owned by ${stats.uid}`);
}
```

You can also implement your own, just return a promise (this example is reading a http request):

```
function read_request(request) {
    request.setEncoding("utf-8");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var cache = "";
      request.on("data", (chunk) => {
         cache += cache;
      }).on("end", () => {
         resolve(cache);
      }).on("error", reject);
     });
}
```

Comment: This only work for regular callback accepting functions. Not Stream object returning functions.

Comment: I added another example to show a custom function which read a http request, may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stream finish event to determine when the file unzip is complete. We can then use promises and async / await to ensure we don't try to apply the filter before the files are ready.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;
const unzipper = require('unzipper');
const dir = __dirname + "/";

function unzipFile(fileName, outputPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let createdFile = dir + fileName
        let stream = fs.createReadStream(createdFile)
            .pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: outputPath }));

        stream.on('finish', () => {
            console.log('file unzipped');
            resolve(outputPath);
        });
    });
}

function applyFilter(Name) {
    fs.readdir(dir, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            data.filter(file => file.includes("png")).forEach(file => {
                let greyPNG = (__dirname + '/' + Name + '/' + file)
                console.log (greyPNG)
                fs.createReadStream(greyPNG)
                    .pipe(new PNG({
                        colorType: 0,
                    }))
                    .on('parsed', function () {
                        this.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(greyPNG));
                    });
            })  
        }
    })
}

async function unzipAndApplyFilter(zipFile, outputPath) {
    await unzipFile(zipFile, outputPath); // Wait until unzip is complete.
    applyFilter(outputPath);
}

unzipAndApplyFilter('myfile.zip', 'myfile');
```